# jquery $.getJSON returning undefined variable, JSON data present

Tags: jquery, json, get, undefined

I'm currently working on cross domain data transfer and I've hit a really big block, I've spent hours & hours trying to get this to work, it seems to be the correct way of doing it so any pointers would be greatly received.

I'm using jquery & the getJSON to return a id from a php page that json_encodes the data;

My jquery code is `

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.icetrack.it/scripts/php/data/ipAddress.php",

    {    
        location: locationVar,
        user_key: user_key,
        refer: refer,
        title: title,   
        async:false,        
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

             alert(data);
        }
                 },"json");
```

which talks to a php page that outputs nothing other than,

```
echo json_encode(array("id"=>"$id")); ?>
```

This page outputs JSON as such

```
{"id":"198"}
```

Yet all my jquery will return is a undefined variable, where am I going wrong this is driving mad!

Thanks all!

Comment: Be sure to have a real good reason to be using synchronised (`async:false`). Your page will wait for this to finish, and if it doesn't it becomes unresponsive. Better find a way around that by calling subsequent functions in the success, so the page won't lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the wrong parameters to `$.getJSON()` - many of the ones you've supplied only work for `$.ajax()`.

In particular, the `data` parameter for `$.getJSON()` is for *CGI* parameters to be sent to the server, not for arbirtrary `$.ajax()` parameters.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://www.icetrack.it/scripts/php/data/ipAddress.php",
     data: {    
        location: locationVar,
        user_key: user_key,
        refer: refer,
        title: title
     },
     async:false,        
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the speedy response, I've got this working from within the same domain, Although i'm trying to send across two domains - Is this the same $.ajax call?

Comment: if you're going cross domain you either need an `Access-Allow-Origin` header in the PHP, or JSONP output

Comment: thanks very much! been looking for that for AGES! thanks again!